# Template from parent to child component doesn't re-render

Tags: angular

I got a modal wrapper component (`child.component`) that uses the template from parent (`parent.component`).

But the variable in the template won't be re-rendered even the `someFunction()` is triggered from within the parent. It just remains as the default value 999 in this case.

How can I make sure the template re-render whenever the parent's variable `order` is updated?

**parent.component.html**

```
<div>parent content</div>

<ng-template #temp> 
  <div>{{ order.Id }}</div>   <!-- THIS DOESN'T RE-RENDER -->
</ng-template>

<app-modal-wrapper [temp]="temp"></app-modal-wrapper>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  public order: any = { Id: 999 }; 

  public someFunction(x) {
    this.order = { Id: x };
  }
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="temp"></ng-container>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-wrapper',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() temp: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

note. I refer to this guide to pass template from parent to child component:
https://medium.com/geekculture/angular-3-ways-you-can-pass-templates-from-parent-to-child-components-to-promote-reusability-ba0a0bfb77c6

Comment: What is your ChangeDetectionStrategy?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng content](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection) instead of an input with ng-template. It seems way more appropriate.

ChildComponent.html =>

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

ParentComponent.html =>

```
<div>parent content</div>

<app-modal-wrapper><div>{{ order.Id }}</div></app-modal-wrapper>
```